# QWebView troubling with loading HTML in PyQt4

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pyqt4, qwebview

I've built a little app that loads a map in an QWebView. It works perfect when using Python 3.4 win64... 
When I want to execute the same code using Python 2.7 win32. the html file doesn't appear. 
Somebody can explain me why it happens and how to resolve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import folium
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

mapa = folium.Map(location=[46.3014, -123.7390], zoom_start=7)
mapa.save("test.html")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
strona = QWebView() 
strona.load(QUrl("test.html")) 
strona.show() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little investigation I've found out that the reason of not showing a map is a company policy. When opening a webpage as google.com I’ve got the information that webpage is blocked.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
strona = QWebView() 
strona.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com")) 
strona.show() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
When opening a map created by folium there is no information. Not sure why...
[image]

What’s  more I've checked at not-company win32, python 2.7 and the app has worked fine.

Summing up, there is nothing wrong with the code or the python's version. It is the company policy.

Nevertheless it is interesting that I can open google.com or test.html using web browser as like Google Chrome or Internet Explorer....

Answer (score 0):

Gotta say, sounds like a whitelist. and the 64/32 bit is the key, 2 different paths are being used, which is why one works and one doesnt, you should try the 64 bit on google, and see if it works. If it does, then you just curtailed the company whitelist, And confirmed it is one.

Comment: Actually I have only my privte win64 and here app shows seamlessly a map or any web. There are only win32 at my job there